# Fade in and show page slowing with JQuery when visibility is initially hidden

Tags: jquery, css

Ok, suppose I had a body element in my stylesheet and I set `visibility:hidden;` When the page is loaded I would like to use `.fadeIn` and fade in the page slowly.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
$("body").css("visibility", 'visible').fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of visibility, set the opacify to 0 and then use animate to get the best effect.

```
$("body").css("opacity", 0).animate({ opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnWv6/)**

You can set the initial opacity to 0 through css itself which will give even better effect. With that the code is reduced to just.

```
$("body").animate({ opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

Comment: Good solution, but be aware that opacity isn't supported on IE8 or earlier without a filter property, and because opacity is only part of the W3C recommendation, it's not a universal rule. I think jQuery's fadeIn addresses this issue (but I'm not 100% sure at the moment).

Comment: @Matt - Using `css` method of jQuery to set `opacity` takes care of cross browser issues, so you can use it without any worries.

Comment: Valid; it is good to know that. I would have been tempted to just set "opacity" in my CSS rules directly.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
$("body").css("display", 'none').fadeIn("slow");
```

`fadeIn` works on elements with `display: none`.  Also, setting visibility to visible will have it shown, not hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvG5G/

Comment: Just set the CSS rule in the CSS for the page; otherwise flickering is likely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, set `display: none` for body.

Your JS would be `$("body").fadeIn("slow");`

That works!

Comment: True; I think we're assuming the scope is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

initially hide the `body` with `css`, `display:none;`

```
$("body").hide(0).delay(2000).fadeIn("slow");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6yZT/8/)

`.delay` is only added for demonstration purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

This is the easiest way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvG5G/1/